# Regex to validate the input rules

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate using regex the user input to see if match the following rules.

Valid input:

```
2-000000000000
1-234342324342
...
```

Rules:

1. It has to be 13 digit numbers, no string.
2. Allow hyphen - come after the first character.
3. Allow space before and after the hyphen - character.

Here's what I tried in PHP, but still not correct:

```
if(preg_match("/[0-9?\-[0-9]/i])) {

  echo "matched";

}
```

Comment: Maybe `preg_match("/^\d ?- ?\d{12}\z/", $string)`? Note your string literal is malformed.  Also, `[0-9?\-[0-9]` is a malformed regex that matches a digit, `?`, `-` or `[` chars. `i` is irrelevant here, there are no letters in the pattern.

Comment: You can use `^\d(?:\h*-\h*)?\d{12}$`

Comment: `It has to be 13 digit numbers, no string.` - regex works _only_ on strings, also `2-000000000000` is not even a number in first place

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - it works, thank for that.  Regarding the space, how to allow one or more space? I test it and its only match one space, but I want to allow one or more spaces before and after the hyphen.

Comment: @mana: I have already provisioned for any no of spaces in my comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your double-quoted string literal is malformed, the closing `"` is missing.

Also, mind that `[0-9?\-[0-9]` is a malformed regex that matches a digit, `?`, `-` or `[` char. The `i` flag is irrelevant here, since there are no letters in the pattern.

I suggest using

```php
preg_match("/^\d *- *\d{12}\z/", $string)
```

If the spaces can be any whitespace, replace the literal spaces with `\s`.

Note the use of `\z` anchor, I prefer it to `$` in validation scenarios, since `$` can match before the final line feed char in the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJrFfE/1) (`\z` replaced with `$` since the input is a single multiline string there).